# Change email templates workflow notifications

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share, alfresco-webscripts

I'm trying to change the mail template of workflow notifications, and I also can change the template with the file wf-email.html.ftl of Data Dictionary.

But the subject "You have been assigned a task", I don't know how can I change this.

How can I do this?

Comment: Did you tried changing the properties file?

Comment: The answer is definitely in that other post. As it says, just add a new property named "assigned-task" to your properties bundle, like "assigned-task=Whatever You Want" and that will change the subject.

Comment: "assigned-task=Whatever You Want" is cool, buto how do you make it dynamic??